# Once I get reference to object once copy of array

Tags: javascript, callback, reference, ecmascript-6

I have this code :

```
testObj = [
    {param: 'blue'},
    {param: 'green'}
];

function testFunction(callBack){
    callBack(testObj[0]);
}

testFunction((param) => {
    param = {param: 'red'};
});

console.error(testObj);
```

And after execution I get :

[Console err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCyAC.png)

Why the main object doesn't change if I putted object into callBack function and it should be a reference but instead of this I get newly coppied obj.

On the other side when I am workin on array I get reference :

```
testObj = [
    {param: 'blue'},
    {param: 'green'}
];

function testFunction(callBack){
    callBack(testObj, 0);
}

testFunction((arr, index) => {
    arr[index] = {param: 'red'};
});

console.error(testObj);
```

And I get changed array :

[Console err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhxno.png)

From my knowledge primitives should be coppied, but objects should be passed as a reference. So I was expecting changing data on the first example also.

Why It haven't happend ?

Comment: Call `param.param =  'red'` to change the passed object.

Comment: You just changed the `param` argument's value to some new object. The value in the array is still the same.

Comment: `testFunction((param) => {    param.param= 'red';
});` instead of assigning new object to param change property of param object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The param has to be set referring to the object, try running the 2 code snippets. You are changing the value of the param but not the value in the array

```js
testObj = [
    {param: 'blue'},
    {param: 'green'}
];

function testFunction(callBack){
    callBack(testObj[0]);
}

testFunction((param) => {
    param = {param: 'red'};
    // changes would not get reflected globally
    console.log('debug', param);
    // changes would get reflected locally
});

console.log(testObj);
```

```js
testObj = [
    {param: 'blue'},
    {param: 'green'}
];

function testFunction(callBack){
    callBack(testObj[0]);
}

testFunction((param) => {
    param.param =  'red';
});

console.log(testObj);
```

Comment: `param = {param: 'red'};` line assign new part of memory because {} "braces" creates **new** object in memory. Now I understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the main object doesn't change if I putted object into callBack function and it should be a reference

You've changed the value in the `param` argument (`param = ...`). You haven't changed the state of the object. But in your array example, you change the state of the array (`arr[index] = ...`).

> but instead of this I get newly coppied obj.

No, it's not a copy. It's the same object.

An equivalent to your array example would set a property on the object:

```js
testObj = [
    {param: 'blue'},
    {param: 'green'}
];

function testFunction(callBack){
    callBack(testObj[0]);
}

testFunction((param) => {
    param.param = {param: 'red'};
// -^^^^^^
});

console.error(testObj);
```

---

Side-note: Unless you've declared `testObj` somewhere, that code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*.

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*